# How to make indexes in SDN4 with embedded database?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

Spring Data Neo4j 4 does not support @Index annotation anymore. With standalone Neo4j database I have to deploy indexes on my own using its REST or web interface. However, with database in embedded mode there are no such interfaces. Do I have to deploy database in standalone mode, set appropriate indexes and then use database folder in embedded mode or use neo4j-shell to access database deployed by SDN4 after stopping the server with my application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do what you suggested, or you can also get a handle to the GraphDatabaseService in your application and create the index using the Java API. Here's an example:

```
 EmbeddedDriver embeddedDriver = (EmbeddedDriver) Components.driver();
 GraphDatabaseService databaseService =  embeddedDriver.getGraphDatabaseService();
 try (Transaction tx = databaseService.beginTx()) {
    databaseService.index().forNodes(indexName);
    ...
    tx.success();
  }
```

**Update based on comment:**

If using the HttpDriver, then you can send a request to the rest endpoint

```
 String uri = Components.driver().getConfiguration().getURI() +
                            "/db/data/...";
 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
 //Construct the JSON statements
 try {
      httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json.toString()));
      HttpRequest.execute(httpClient, httpPost,
                                   Components.driver().getConfiguration().getCredentials());
      } catch (Exception e) {
             //Handle any exceptions
      }
```

Comment: I assume that such direct manipulation is possible only with EmbeddedDriver?

Comment: Access to the GraphDatabaseService is only possible with the EmbeddedDriver, yes. Updated my answer to include sample code for the HttpDriver